# Nitrogen wash beans VS Fresh

Tags: espresso, beans, freshness

I live in a really small area. The closet roaster to me is roughly an hour drive away.

I know how big of a role that using fresh beans play in making quality espresso. Because I may not be able to make it to the roaster on a regular basis, I was curious about LaVazza coffee.

I have heard and read online that LaVazza uses a nitrogen wash on all of their beans that keep them fresh longer. How do they perform compared to fresh beans? Obviously they wont be identical, but will they produce a nice fully bodied espresso with a decent amount of crema?

Comment: Even marijuana is packed with N20 wash.  Many other products are. My take is the beans go stale ... slightly slower

Answer (score 1):

The correct term is [**nitrogen flushing**](https://www.verywellfit.com/nitrogen-flushing-protects-and-preserves-foods-2505948) and it does appear to increase the stored shelf life of roasted beans.  There is a school of thought that using nitrogen (80% of the air we breath) is not a green friendly technique, but it is nevertheless used in other products too.

Comment: In the world of alcoholic beverages they use private preserve. It's just a bottle of heavy inert gas they top the bottle off with after use. I've heard about people using it in their coffee containers too (e.g. after filling their bean hoppers, when they only open their main container every 3/4 days).